# Laravel localization in routes without prefix

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a Laravel app in 9 difference languages:

```
/resources
-- /lang
-- -- /en_US.json
-- -- /fr_FR.json
-- -- /...
```

I'm trying to set up localized URL's like:

```
Route::get(__("link.projects"), 'GuestController@projects');
```

All content on the website is displayed in the correct language but routing returns 404 pages except for default fallback language.

My web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'locale']], function () {

  /* GUEST */
  Route::get('/', 'GuestController@index');
  Route::get(__("link.projects"), 'GuestController@projects');
  Route::get(__("link.participants"), 'GuestController@participants');
  Route::get(__("link.participant")."/{public_id}", 'GuestController@participant');
  Route::get(__("link.about"), 'GuestController@about');
  Route::get(__("link.contact"), 'GuestController@contact');
  

});
```

My locale middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if($request->getHost() == "domain.com") {
        $locale = 'en_US';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.dk") {
        $locale = 'da_DK';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.de") {
        $locale = 'de_DE';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.se") {
        $locale = 'sv_SE';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.fi") {
        $locale = 'fi_FI';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.es") {
        $locale = 'es_ES';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.fr") {
        $locale = 'fr_FR';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.it") {
        $locale = 'it_IT';
      } elseif($request->getHost() == "domain.nl") {
        $locale = 'nl_NL';
      } else {
        $locale = 'en_US';
      }
      if (in_array($locale, [
          "en_US",
          "da_DK",
          "de_DE",
          "sv_SE",
          "fi_FI",
          "es_ES",
          "fr_FR",
          "it_IT",
          "nl_NL"
        ]
      )) {
        session()->put('locale', $locale);
      } else {
        session()->put('locale', 'en_US');
      }

      if(session()->has('locale')) {
          app()->setLocale(session('locale'));
      }

      return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Using the fallback language URLs in production i'm able to get the content localized but URL's in the web.php won't allow translation.
I don't want to have prefix in URL's since the different locales are set by domain instead.

Comment: the routes are registered before that middleware even runs ... *potentially* you could set the locale before the request is handled by the Http Kernel (only based on the host) but the session stuff would have to be done with a middleware

Comment: Do you know how to get the current domain from the web.php? In that case i guess it would be possible to make a simple if statement and then force a localization directly @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i took a small break and figured out a possible solution which seems to be working perfectly.

```
$locales = array("en_US","de_DE","es_ES","it_IT","fr_FR","da_DK","sv_SE","fi_FI","nl_NL");
  foreach($locales as $locale) {
    /* GUEST */
    Route::get(__("link.projects", [], $locale), 'GuestController@projects');
    Route::get(__("link.participants", [], $locale), 'GuestController@participants');
    Route::get(__("link.participant", [], $locale)."/{public_id}", 'GuestController@participant');
    Route::get(__("link.about", [], $locale), 'GuestController@about');
    Route::get(__("link.contact", [], $locale), 'GuestController@contact');
    Route::get(__("link.cookies", [], $locale), 'GuestController@cookies');
    Route::get(__("link.terms_of_use", [], $locale), 'GuestController@terms_of_use');
    Route::get(__("link.privacy_policy", [], $locale), 'GuestController@privacy_policy');
    Route::get(__("link.disclaimer", [], $locale), 'GuestController@disclaimer');

  }
```

Let me know if this has any potential breaks, but for me it's working.

Comment: You could also get your languages array from a config file like `config/locales.php` and it would be more readable and dynamic.

Comment: Perfect. Did update to include the array from configs - however for the answer i'll let it remain. Thank you

Comment: Let's say the user enter https://siteurl.com/kontakt. That 'kontakt' comes from german language. But your application default locale is 'en'. So user will see English translations. I'm using your method for my routes but that problem so disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle this is to use two routes, one for the home page (which generally contains more complex logic like news, pick up articles, banners, etc), and a catch all for any other page.

**Routes**

```
// Home page
Route::get('/', [
    'as'      => 'home',
    'uses'    => 'PageController@index'
]);

// Catch all page controller (place at the very bottom)
Route::get('{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'PageController@getPage' 
])->where('slug', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]+)');
```

The important part to note in the above is the `->where()` method chained on the end of the route. This allows you to declare regex pattern matching for the route parameters. In this case I am allowing alphanumeric characters, hyphens and forward slashes for the `{slug}` parameter.

This will match slugs like

```
test-page
test-page/sub-page
another-page/sub-page
```

you can set your own pattern.

Comment: Will try look into this.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found a perfect solution for you.

After a quick google search I found the following:

Check it out!

https://github.com/codezero-be/laravel-localized-routes

Comment: This still uses prefixes in the URL to determine the localization.